# Connect 2 shapes with line in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

Is it really not possible to connect 2 shapes with a line and keep those 2 shapes freely movable without loosing the connection to the line???

In my opinion a feature found in almost all drawing programs but not in Sketch????

Comment: Well, illustrator does not have it, inkscape does not have it, corel draw does not have it, photoshop does not have it. This kindof disputes all have it.i could make the list longer but i eont want to verify each point. Anyway any graph drawing application has this but thats a different thing entirely.

Comment: @joojaa - actually Inkscape has a Diagram Connector tool which can do this. [See example](https://imgur.com/7rybEC0)

Comment: @BillyKerr yes i stand corrected. But really a connection like this is quite useless in the grand scheme of things. Id much much rather have autolayout.